# Not able to intent to next layout

Tags: java, android, android-intent, layout, imageview

i'm working on my project and i created an interface of my app.
[image]

now i want that when ever i click in image view of Automation i go to my next layout. So i tried to write this code 
[image]
the layout in which i want to move after clicking Automation is this :
[image]
But when i'm running app it's saying

> Application error
>   Unfortunately,animation(name of my project) has stopped.
>   **Logcat:**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.animation.dashboard.onCreate(dashboard.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What's mistake i'm making here ? i'm new to android so kindly help me out here.

Comment: Can you show us error message from logcat ?

Comment: OK, i'm adding image of logcat in my question.

Comment: Please add your code as text and not images

Comment: add code , not image

Comment: Ok so Your view is basically not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view variable is not defined and you are trying to use it as it is null. But on the another hand, I dont think you need this, just go with findViewById without this view

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `view_rooms` is not an activity - the second argument in your intent needs to be the context of the destination.

So if you want to go to new activity change your intent like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(dashboard.this, SecondActivity.class));
```

Comment: view_rooms is new activity, i want to move to view_rooms

Answer (score 1):

You are using this in the dashboard activity line number 25

```
imgauto = view.findViewById(R.id.autoimg)
```

while your variable view is empty you have not assigned it something and also you are in activity so use it directly  like this

```
imgauto = findViewById(R.id.autoimg)
```

try this and i am sure it will work perfectly.

Comment: great sir ask me any time if you need any help in kotlin, android, java